# How not to use functions as parameters for other functions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a few functions that will determine the number of real roots and the roots of a quadratic equations, and I must do it using a `main()` function. What I am trying to avoid is using the final function with all the other functions as its parameters, like

```
def main():
    function4(function3(function2(function1())), function2(function1()))
```

Instead, how can I make it look like:

```
def main():
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
    function4()
```

Comment: Use temporary variables.

Comment: Shouldn't this be just set the result into variables and passing them around?

Comment: Searche for **variables** and **return values**

Comment: If you want it to look *exactly like that*, then you'll probably have to refactor your code so that all your functions do not require arguments, to start with, no? Likely, this will involve the use of global variables. All around, this sounds like a very bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

This should be equivalent.

```
def main():
    result1 = function1()
    result2 = function2(result1)
    result3 = function3(result2)
    final_result = function4(result3, result2)
```